# recursive equation for number of white balls 

Tags: probability-theory, recurrence-relations

Consider a polyurn scheme of more than two colors. Let us draw a ball from the urn and replace it with another ball of the color we picked from the urn. We assume that $w$ is the number of white balls in the total of $N$ balls.

If $S_n$ is the number of white balls in a random sample of $n$ random draws, we need to obtain a recursive equation for $\Pr(S_n=x)$, where we have $$P(S_1=x)= \left(\frac{W}{N} \right)^X \left(\frac{N-W}{N} \right)^{1-X} ,$$ and we have $X=0,1$.

My approach1:

Given:
Sn= Number of white balls in a random sample of n draws.
To start with , we have P(Sn=x) where x =1 , which means we picked a white ball, the probability of picking a white ball can be written as: W/N.

Next we have P(Sn=x) where x=0, which means we did not pick a white ball. Then the probability of NOT picking a hite ball can be written as 1-W/N.

If we combine the first 2 equations i just obtained, we get the probability p(SN=X) =  (W/N)^X  * (1-W/N)^(1-X)  => lets call this equation 3. where u put in values of X as 0 and 1.
Lets put X=1 in equation 3, we get W/N.
Lets put X=0, we get (1-W/N)

**My approach 2:**

P(S2 = 1) which is the probability of getting one white ball in a sample of (n=2) draws.
There can be two ways of drawing the said combination. White- Non White or Non white - Whit.
therefore the probability can be written as:

= 2 * (W/N)*(N-W/N+1)

P(S2=0) which is the probability of getting ZERO white balls in a sample of (n=2) draws.

= 2 * (N-W/N+1) * (N-W+1/N)

P(S3 = 1) which is the probability of getting one white ball in a sample of (n=3) draws.
The various forms the draws can assume are => W-NW-NW , NW-W-NW, NW-NW-W.   (Where NW=> Non white and W=> White)
When we write down the probabilities we obtain:

= [3*(W/N)*(N-W/N+1)*(N-W+1/N+2)]

P(S3=0) which is the probability of getting ZERO white balls in a sample of (n=3) draws.
The various combinations possible are: NW-NW-NW during all the three draws since we get zero white balls.
Writing the probabilities:
= [3*(N-W)*(N-W+1)*(N-W+2)] / [N*(N+1)*(N+2)]

P(S4 = 1) which is the probability of getting one white ball in a sample of (n=4) draws.
The various combinations possible are: W-NW-NW-NW , NW-W-NW-NW, NW-NW-W-NW, NW-NW-NW-W
(Where NW => NON WHITE & W => WHITE)
Writing the probabilities:
=4*(W/N) * ((N-W) / (N+1)) * (N-W+1/ N+2) * ((N-W+2) / (N+3))

P(S4=0) which is the probability of getting ZERO white balls in a sample of (n=4) draws.
The various combinations possible are: (NW-NW-NW-NW ) *4

=4*(N-W/N) * (N-W+1)/(N+1) * (N-W+2 / N+1) * (N-W+3 / N+3)

Comment: Given:
Sn= Number of white balls in a random sample of n draws.
To start with , we have P(Sn=x) where x =1 , which means we picked a white ball, the probability of picking a white ball can be written as: W/N.

Next we have P(Sn=x) where x=0, which means we did not pick a white ball. Then the probability of NOT picking a hite ball can be written as 1-W/N.

If we combine the first 2 equations i just obtained, we get the probability p(SN=X) =  (W/N)^X * (1-W/N)^(1-X)  =>eqn 3. where u put in values of X as 0 and 1.
Lets put X=1 in equation 3, we get W/N.
Lets put X=0, we get (1-W/N)

Comment: @srivatsan could u tell me if my approach to the problem is correct?

Comment: I had a look at your computations. Your P(S2=1) (which I indicated) is correct but explained in a way and written in an order such that I doubt you know why. Your P(S2=0) is wrong.You do not mention P(S2=2) and you do not check that the sum of the nonzeroes P(S2=k) is 1. I did not read further. I suggest you go back to this n=2 case and try to solve it completely and accurately. // Please avoid fallacies like *my god this is only a simple case, how am I going to do the general n case*, the opposite is true! If you solve the n=2 case and understand it, helping you through the rest will be easy.

Answer (score 1):

> could u tell me if my approach to the problem is correct?

No it is not.

For example $P(S_n=0)$ is not $1-P(S_n=1)$ unless $n=1$ because $S_n$ is any integer from $0$ to $n$ with positive probability.

And $P(S_n=1)$ is not $W/N$ unless $n=1$ because one wants the probability that, amongst the $n$ first draws, exactly one produced a white ball. What you write is the probability that the first draw produced a white ball. And note that the total number of balls is not the same before every draw.

Take $n=2$. Then the draw white-nonwhite has probability $(W/N)(1-(W+1)/(N+1))$ (why?) and the draw nonwhite-white has probability $(1-W/N)(W/(N+1))$ (why?) hence $P(S_2=1)$ is their sum $2W(N-W)/(N(N+1))$.

You might want to expand on this and, for starters, to write down the full distribution of $S_2$.

Comment: thanks for the correction and Whats the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: My post is full of leads. Did you try to follow any of them? For starters, you could complete the distribution of $S_2$.

Comment: I could not exactly follow what u wrote here. could you be able to elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I certainly could if I would but, since you seem to refuse to follow **ANY** of the suggestions I made in my post, I fail to see the point. Please do not tell me you cannot complete the distribution of $S_2$, because, as they say, this would [insult my intelligence](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Godfather)... :-)

Comment: I do understand what u hv posted and follow it completely. My question is will the expansion continue as the next two combinations being white-white and then non white-non white?

Comment: Also since u ask "why" next to each of those, here are my eplanations for the same:

Comment: for white-nonwhite , if a white ball is picked the probability becomes W/N, we keep back the white ball with another white ball. Hence the value of the number of white balls increases by 1. it becomes w+1 and the number of balls in total is n+1. Therefore the probability of not getting a white ball now becomes 1-(w+1)/(n+1). The same logic holds good for the next combination too.

Comment: I have derived the equations for the various trials S2, S3 and i got the distribution for each. Could you tell me how i now co relate that with the main equation

Comment: I suggest you post the full distributions of $S_2$ and $S_3$ you computed, as an appendix to your question, and that we then try to understand them so as to generalize them to the $S_n$ case for every $n$.

Comment: could u kindly share ur email id, i will mail u the distribution i got for s2, s3 an s4. I dont want to post if here as the comment thrad is getting really long. or would i be able to send u a msg.

Comment: As. An. Appendix. To. Your. Question. (See my last comment.) A paragraph *My approach 2*, if you wish.

Comment: could u send me ur email id so that i could email u my distributions for s2 an s3. Its too much to type here as a comment.

Comment: If you modify your QUESTION to append your solution to it, the length is nearly unlimited.

Comment: Okay im posting it right away

Comment: @d\Didier Piau could u tell me how to proceed i posted the equations

Comment: And I commented on them, as you know. As long as you do not comply with the elementary remarks I made about the new part of your main post, called *My approach*, we cannot progress.

Comment: I edited the question with approaches as requested

Comment: P(S2=0) is still wrong. P(S2=2) is still missing. I did not read the S3 and S4 parts but they are obviously incomplete. My suggestion: forget S3 and S4, and compute the full distribution of S2. So, you need three numbers P(S2=0), P(S2=1) and P(S2=2), nonnegative, whose sum is 1. Let us start with P(S2=0). You write this is 2((N-W)/(N+1))((N-W+1)/N) (I guess). Why? What are the meanings of the factors 2, (N-W)/(N+1) and (N-W+1)/N? And here is an auxiliary question: how many balls are in the urn after the first draw?